# Include all cmake files contained in a folder

Tags: cmake, include

I would like to avoid to write all lines like:

```
SET ( MYPROJECT_CMAKE_MACRO_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake )

INCLUDE ( ${MYPROJECT_CMAKE_MACRO_DIR}/firstexample.cmake ) 
INCLUDE ( ${MYPROJECT_CMAKE_MACRO_DIR}/secondexample.cmake ) 
...
```

And include all the files in the folder cmake. Is there a command or some algorithm in order to do that?

Thanks

Comment: With some good editor like Sublime or Kate and an `ls *cmake` in your terminal you write this code in no time. Or what's your rationale here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file(GLOB ...)` to identify the group of files to include, and then use a `foreach` loop. For example:

```
file(GLOB cmakeFiles ${MYPROJECT_CMAKE_MACRO_DIR}/*.cmake)
foreach(cmakeFile ${cmakeFiles})
    message("INCLUDE ${cmakeFile}")
    INCLUDE(${cmakeFile})
endforeach(cmakeFile)
```

You could make this into a function, and then use it multiple times, however, `CMakeLists.txt` inherits from its parent context, so usually including a file at the root `CMakeLists.txt` is sufficient.